# More Intelligent Eclipse "Open Call Hierarchy"?

Tags: java, eclipse, call-hierarchy

If I have a Java project in Eclipse, I can right-click on a method name and "Open Call Hierarchy."  Suppose I have two interfaces, A and B, that both specify a method x().  Is it possible for me to have Eclipse use "Open Call Hierarchy" in a more intelligent way so as to only show calls to x() from A's while not showing those from B's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse should already do this. If you want to test it, go to your *A* interface, select the *x()* method and run 'Open Call Hierarchy' on it. Do the same for your *x()* method in interface *B*. You should get different code locations, unless you have a class which implements both, which you should never do. Doing so won't break any compilation or execution, you will just be doubly declaring the same method signature.

Comment: Now I'm starting to confuse myself.  When I actually tried the dummy example it behaves as you explain, but my real example with more complicated hierarchies *appears* to suffer from the phenomenon that I described.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this with a frequently-overridden method, toString(). When I right-click on it and choose "Open Call Hierarchy," Eclipse happily searches through my entire workspace and returns all references to that method signature.

I often rely on Eclipse to go the opposite way: I select a method invocation and press F3 to Open Declaration. But I don't think Eclipse is able to go the direction you want, from the declaration to the calling reference.

Answer (score 3):

It may help to remove "Potential matches" from the search results.  Try this:

`Preferences -> General -> Search`

And check "Ignore potential matches".