# Find methods calls in Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, find

I have a class X containing method myMethod(). I would like to find locations in all projects in my current workspace where this myMethod() is being called. I cannot use any search functions as there are several classes with myMethod(), and it isn't static. Hence I need to know the name of the objects of this  class, which isn't possible without manually exploring the projects.

Does Eclipse have a solution for this?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650021/more-intelligent-eclipse-open-call-hierarchy

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Go to the method in X.java, and select Open Call Hierarchy from the context menu.

Comment: I did not know this. I was using `CTRL-G` shortcut and it wasn't working, as in it would not result the method in question being called from another method in the same class. Any ideas why this is? ...nevermind! `CTRL-SHIFT-G` is for finding references, `CTRL-G` is for finding declarations! :S

Comment: in my eclipse here (mars) the shortcut is ctrl+alt+h :)

Comment: I tried all I could find, Ctrl+Shift+G, ctrl+Alt+H and bunch more but all show me "The resource is not on the build path of a Java project".  So, none work.  Someone suggested to right click on project in the tree and choose "build path" from context menu, but I dont see this.  I am on eclipse photon.  Thanks

Comment: SHORTCUT:  **Ctrl+Shift+H**

Answer (score 58):

Select `mymethod()` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.

To see some detailed Information about any method you can use this by selecting that particular Object or method and right click. you can see the **"*OpenCallHierarchy*"** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). Like that many tools are there to make your work Easier like "**Quick Outline**" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) to view the Datatypes and methods declared in a particular .java file.

To know more about this, refer this [eclipse Reference](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_call_hierarchy_view.htm)

Comment: ...which opens call hierarchy.

Comment: I tried all I could find, Ctrl+Shift+G, ctrl+Alt+H, Ctrl+O and bunch more but all show me "The resource is not on the build path of a Java project".  So, none work.  Someone suggested to right click on project in the tree and choose "build path" from context menu, but I dont see this.  I am on eclipse photon.  Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can also search for specific methods. For e.g. If you want to search for `isEmpty()` method of the string class you have to got to - **Search -> Java ->** type **`java.lang.String.isEmpty()`** and in the 'Search For' option use **Method**.

You can then select the scope that you require.

Answer (score 9):

Move the cursor to the method name. Right click and select References > Project or References > Workspace from the pop-up menu.

Answer (score 6):

```
select method > right click > References > Workspace/Project (your preferred context )
```

or

```
(Ctrl+Shift+G)
```

This will show you a Search view containing the hierarchy of class and method which using this method.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on method and click on **Open call Hierarchy**

[image: eclipse right click call hierarchy]

Comment: I tried all I could find, Ctrl+Shift+G, ctrl+Alt+H and bunch more but all show me "The resource is not on the build path of a Java project".  So, none work.  Someone suggested to right click on project in the tree and choose "build path" from context menu, but I dont see this.  I am on eclipse photon.  Thanks

Comment: @pixel - Please do "mvn clean install". Then try again. It might be happening because your project is not build properly.