# How to search for instances of a class using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I want to find instances of a class and modify some of the properties of one of the instance. But i cannot find a way to break in a block of code that references that class, so that it may appear in the variables view. What i'm thinking is to pause the jvm and the search for instances of MyClass but i can't find a tool to do this. Someone got an idea ?

Comment: The eclipse debugger lets you do that. If your class has the right setters, you can do it in the `Expression` view using the object reference and calling the setters (of course, I would hate doing this).

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268998/find-methods-calls-in-eclipse-project/13966182

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would open the call-hierarchie of the constructor of this class. Mark the constructor, left click, call hierarchie. That will give you a list wherever the object gets instantiated.

Comment: How can I search this if the class does not have an explicit constructor?

Comment: @CarlosSantos (might be a little late) but you can right-click on the class itself and show call hierarchy too, it will show all the constructors including implicit.