# Eclipse - Find Java references of a library without attached sources

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

## Environment

I have a simple `test-foo.jar` library with just two files:

- interface `Foo` with a single method `void doStuff()`
- class `Bar` with a single method `void executeFoo(Foo foo)`, which just calls `foo.doStuff()`

Then I have Eclipse Java project with a single class `FooImpl` which implements `Foo`. This project has `test-foo.jar` as a build path entry. I don't have source codes for this JAR attached.

[image: Eclipse project tree]

## The Problem

Now lets say I am a bit curious about who actually calls `doStuff()` method. So I click on the `FooImpl#doStuff` signature and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (find references). I expect to see `Bar#executeFoo` in the search results, but the results are actually empty.

[image: Empty search results]

## The Question

I am bit confused as I thought this works in Eclipse (been using Eclipse for more than a few years now). But it seems it only works for libraries with sources attached (which I didn't notice before).

**Is there a way how to find references (or usage) of a type (or method) in project libraries without sources attached?** Why does not Eclipse index and show references from `.class` files?

---

**Additional info**:

- Finding references works as soon as I attach source codes to the JAR.
- I am interested in knowing why Eclipse JDT developers decided to *not index* or *search* `.class` without sources.
- Note, that knowing *who is calling* my method is very useful information even if I don't have source codes.
- Seems to me that Eclipse [is indexing method references](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/search/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/search/indexing/BinaryIndexer.java#n602) in `.class` files.
- And by the way NetBeans "don't work" as well ;).

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268998/find-methods-calls-in-eclipse-project

Comment: @MikeKoch nope... OP in that question does not know about *Find References* functionality. Call hierarchy is just a different view on method references. I know (at least I think I know :)) how to search for references. It just don't work if the library does not have sources attached.

Comment: If bar does not reference fooImpl.doStuff(), but, instead, references foo.doStuff() then it will not match the search for references to the fooImpl.doStuff() method.

Comment: Just for curiosity, have you tried installing a Java Decompiler on eclipse to see if it helps?

Comment: @EvertonAgner It helps, but at least one source class needs to be opened before the source files are produced. However I have pretty bad experience with both JAD and JD plugins as they usually cause SEGFAULT (or similar fatal issue) which kills Eclipse.

Comment: **UPDATE** Stephan Herrmann (one of JDT committers) answered my question on Eclipse forums. I am waiting for one clarification, then I will post some summary here. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/639229/1234221/#msg_1234221

Answer (score 0):

You need the source attached to your library. There's no point for Eclipse to take you to the .class file since all you would see is a bunch of compiled jamble-wamble (that's just a word I came up with). Eclipse will only navigate to Java source files.

Comment: Do you know why is this the case? Is there any mailing list discussion connected to this or any other official reference? For me, it would still be very useful to know the component, which is calling my interface.

Comment: No, I don't have an official reference, it's just what it is. Why do you need to know the component? What is it you plan to do once you find it?

Comment: I need to reverse engineer few components. Just knowing the component which is creating a specific object instance would be of a great value. Without this I need to manually decompile all JARs and attach the source files and then search for references.

Comment: And that's why the functionality you're asking does not exist. Eclipse is not there to help you reverse engineer or decompile JAR's. What you're trying to do in most cases will even be unethical.

Comment: I get that you probably never faced any integration issues when using Java together with some closed source third-party library ;). Or when you need to implement additional functionality where the official documentation is almost non-existent and Google returns exactly 0 results. There is nothing unethical trying to understand how something works.

Comment: Well, if the library you're using is not good enough, it's time to move on to a better one I suppose.