# java: how to check methods calling within a project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, testng

I have given a small project to understand the flow and functionality.
I am a fresher.
This project contains 3 packages with each containing 4 to 5 java classes.
now I study a method and confused with its calling. Is there any way to know fwhere where in the project, that method is called from.
If i try running single single classes , then few methods don't get called so not able to see their exact output.

Comment: import the project into eclipse and debug your project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find methods calls in Eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268998/find-methods-calls-in-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple go to the `yourmethod()` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Create a project out of it in editors like Eclipse or Intellij Idea. Right click on method you would get options to get method callers.

Answer (score 0):

Import your project in Eclipse and for each method highlight it and right click and select "Open Call Hierarchy" you will get all the method calls for that method in the view "Call Hierarchy".Expand and you will get the flow.