# When "public HttpEntity<RepositoryLinksResource> listRepositories()" method will be called?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When `public HttpEntity<RepositoryLinksResource> listRepositories()` method will be called? in spring boot what exactly this method do? If something not found to this method what exception it will throw?

Comment: What do you want to know? Can you show the code?

Comment: To find usages of a method, in Eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268998/find-methods-calls-in-eclipse-project, in IJ: Alt-F7: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-usages-method-options.html