# set javadoc to print where a method is called?

Tags: java, javadoc

Im deconstructing a project.  Is there a way to tell javadoc to print a listing of where a method is called?

Meaning in its description of a method, you have the normal javadoc stuff, but is there a way to tell it to put a line below that which would say "Called By: X, Y, Z"?  I seem to remember that in some obscure javadocs in the past, i just don't remember where and how anymore.  I can't find a setting as of yet so if its possible, im assuming it would be a doclet tool of some kind.

Comment: Something like that will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650021/more-intelligent-eclipse-open-call-hierarchy

Comment: Its for analysis purposes.  Most people planning the modifications won't have the code, they need a printout.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with javadoc.  http://www.jdocs.com/ shows usage for some public APIs, but this isn't clearly isn't what you're looking for.  I'd recommend setting up the code as a project in an IDE such as Eclipse or IDEA and find references from there.